# Partition table in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with billion rows each containing edges(geometries), some of which are duplicates and I'm using the following queries to delete the duplicated edges.

```
    DELETE FROM  water_edges 
    WHERE id IN (
    SELECT e1.id 
    FROM water_edges e1, water_edges e2
    WHERE st_equals(e1.geom_line, e2.geom_line)
    AND e1.id < e2.id
    );
```

However, I have 8 cores to use and I want to make full use of it, How do I change the query or create a function to say run deletion function on subsets only running concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that (yet).

You could run several of these queries in parallel.
If you decide to run 8 in parallel, add `AND e1.id % 8 = 0` to the first, `AND e1.id % 8 = 1` to the second and so on.

Query speed will not scale linearly. If you are lucky, the queries can share the same sequential scan, but it may well be that your I/O system becomes the bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

What I have usually done in these cases is to create a script that divides key space into contiguous blocks and apportions the queries to connections in a connection pool.

This works better than the modulus because chances are good that tuples that are close by eachother in key space may be in the same pages (if this is an insert-heavy workload) and therefore you minimise waiting and transferring buffers between cores.

If you go this approach note that libpq (and hence most client-side drivers) support asynchronous queries, so you can fire off queries to every connection in a pool and then periodically poll, and fire off more queries when the connection is available.